# Resta en R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

alguien sabe como podria restar el prewt - postwt?, estoy dentro de la tabla anorexia en R

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No añadas imágenes de tu código, tienes la posibilidad de añadir el texto en claro para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: La forma básica: `anorexia$Prewt - anorexia$Postwt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que entendí solo quieres restar esos 2 valores,  podrías usar el paquete `dplyr` y quedaría así:

```
library(dplyr)

Resultado = anorexia %>%
  mutate(Resta = Prewt - Postwt)
```

Generaría otra tabla que sea `resultado`, sino quieres que se genere otra tabla aparte, saca la parte donde puse `" Resultado ="`

```
#Resulado de la resta

     Treat Prewt Postwt Resta
1     cont  80.7   80.2   0.5
2     cont  89.4   80.1   9.3
3     cont  91.8   86.4   5.4
4     cont  74.0   86.3 -12.3
5     cont  78.1   76.1   2.0
6     cont  88.3   78.1  10.2
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitabas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió

Comment: Me alegro. Saludos